# Laggy PC with Kernel 6.5 and AMD 5500U Lucienne

Tags: linux, kernel, performance, cpu-frequency

I am currently facing a problem with my Lenovo E15 laptop (AMD Ryzen 5500u "Lucienne" processor) and the kernel 6.5. (Xubuntu 22.04)

Maybe three weeks ago,
I noticed that my computer was having a laggy behaviour,
applications were slow,
Wi-Fi had hiccups where it took many seconds to respond,
and of course internet surfing was awful.

I was looking for a cause for all this,
and I finally discovered that the CPU governors had changed.

Before, I mainly used two governors on this computer:

- Ondemand: most of the time I use this governor.
  It uses the good CPU clock for the need (1.4 GHz lowest)
- powersave: when I play 2D games on the computer,
  I use this governor to reduce heating and vents
  as they were fluid at 1.4 GHz.

And the new ones:

- powersave: seems to behave like ondemand governor
  before but reduces the clock even more (0.4 GHz lowest)
- performance: max out the CPU clock (4.0 GHz?)

I thought that there was a bug in the kernel,
so I decided to update it with mainline software,
but the newest kernel (6.7.8 ?) has the same problem.

When I switch back to 6.2 kernel (exactly 6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1),
the problems disappear. 
This is what I do for the moment, but Ubuntu 24.04 is pointing out and will I be able to keep 6.2 kernel with it?

What other things I could test?